# How do I create a hashed map of integers to vectors?

Tags: ada

I am learning Ada (by trying https://adventofcode.com/2018/ problems).

I have a vector `ActivityVector` of `ActivityRecord` records:

```
type ActivityRecord is 
record
   dt: Ada.Calendar.Time;
   str: UStr.Unbounded_String;
end record;

package ActivityVector is new Ada.Containers.Vectors
   (Element_Type => ActivityRecord,
   Index_Type => Natural);
```

And I want to put these in a map where the keys are `Integer`s. I have the following:

```
function IntegerHash(i: Integer) return Ada.Containers.Hash_Type;

package ActivityMap is new Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Hashed_Maps(
   Key_Type => Integer,
   Element_Type => Activity.ActivityVector.Vector,
   Hash => IntegerHash,
   Equivalent_Keys => "="
);
```

When I try to compile this, I get:

```
act_map.ads:9:04: instantiation error at a-cihama.ads:46
act_map.ads:9:04: no visible subprogram matches the specification for "="
act_map.ads:9:04: instantiation error at a-cihama.ads:46
act_map.ads:9:04: default "=" on "Vector" is not directly visible
```

It looks like it is expecting an equality operator defined for the vector?
I could define one, but first I would like to check that:

- My thinking is correct on what is required
- If there is an easier way to implement this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It looks like it is expecting an equality operator defined for the vector

Yes.

> I could define one

Don't do that, just use the existing function defined in your instantiation of `Ada.Containers.Vectors`:

```
package ActivityMap is new Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Hashed_Maps(
   Key_Type => Integer,
   Element_Type => Activity.ActivityVector.Vector,
   Hash => IntegerHash,
   Equivalent_Keys => "=",
   "=" => Activity.ActivityVector."="
);
```

Or, make the `Activity.ActivityVector."="` function directly visible by doing

```
use type Activity.ActivityVector.Vector;
```

Comment: Thanks - what's the reason that an equality operator is required? I'm guessing to avoid an unnecessary write if the value already matches?

Comment: `=` on the element type is required for implementing `=` on the map type. I don't think implementations typically do deduplication with it (which is what you suggest) and I think it actually isn't possible without violating the specified API, at least since `Reference_Type` was added with Ada 2012.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks again.